# Importrange changes the format only for a couple cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, importrange, google-sheets-cell-format

I am using importrange and for some cells google sheets changes the format of only a couple cells. I have attached a screenshot. The original worksheet has the correct dates M/DD/YYYY. So I am wondering why only 5-7 cells have a different formatting out of over 1000 rows?

[image: Date format]

Comment: Check the formatting of those 7 cells, you will notice that it is different from the others ... it does not depend on the formula

Comment: There is no way for us to be certain of what is happening with the provided information. What is cell formatting in the source sheet and the destination sheet? What are the values shown in the formula bar for the source cells ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.